# How can i list all webcams installed on my computer using angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, webcam

So far i can access my webcan and show the streaming and take a snapshot. What i want to do in the end is change the source for another webcam, so first i will need to list all webcam installed and if possible, select another source. Any ideas on how to access and list all webcams using angularJS?

Code so far:

```
<script>

    /////////////////////////////////////////////

    var getUserMedia = function() {
      if (navigator.getUserMedia) return navigator.getUserMedia;
      else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) return navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
      else if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) return navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
      else if (navigator.msGetUserMedia) return navigator.msGetUserMedia;
      else return undefined;
    }

    //console.log(getUserMedia());

    /////////////////////////////////////////////

    angular.module('app')
    .factory('CameraService', function($window) {
      var hasUserMedia = function() {
        return !!getUserMedia();
      }

      var getUserMedia = function() {
        navigator.getUserMedia = ($window.navigator.getUserMedia || 
                                  $window.navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                                  $window.navigator.mozGetUserMedia || 
                                  $window.navigator.msGetUserMedia);
        return navigator.getUserMedia;
      }

      return {
        hasUserMedia: hasUserMedia(),
        getUserMedia: getUserMedia
      }
    })

    ////////////////////////////////////////////

    angular.module('app')
    .controller('CameraController', function($scope, CameraService) {
      $scope.hasUserMedia = CameraService.hasUserMedia;
    })

    ////////////////////////////////////////////

    angular.module('app')
    .directive('camera', function(CameraService) {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        controller: function($scope, $q, $timeout) {
            this.takeSnapshot = function() {
                var canvas  = document.querySelector('canvas'),
                    ctx     = canvas.getContext('2d'),
                    videoElement = document.querySelector('video'),
                    d       = $q.defer();

                canvas.width = $scope.w;
                canvas.height = $scope.h;

                $timeout(function() {
                  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, $scope.w, $scope.h);
                  ctx.drawImage(videoElement, 0, 0, $scope.w, $scope.h);
                  d.resolve(canvas.toDataURL());
                }, 0);
                return d.promise;
            }
        },

        template: '<div class="camera"><video class="camera" my-stream config="config" autoplay="" /><div ng-transclude></div><canvas></div>',
        link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
          var w = attrs.width || 640,
              h = attrs.height || 480;

          if (!CameraService.hasUserMedia) return;
          var userMedia = CameraService.getUserMedia(),
              videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
          var onSuccess = function(stream) {
          if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
            videoElement.mozSrcObject = stream;
          } else {
            var vendorURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            videoElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
          }
          // Just to make sure it autoplays
          videoElement.play();
        }
        // If there is an error
        var onFailure = function(err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
        // Make the request for the media
        navigator.getUserMedia({
          video: {
            mandatory: {
              maxHeight: h,
              maxWidth: w
            }
          }, 
          audio: true
        }, onSuccess, onFailure);

        scope.w = w;
        scope.h = h;
        }
      }
    });

    angular.module('app').directive('cameraControlSnapshot', function() {
        return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: '^camera',
        scope: true,
        template: '<a class="btn btn-info" ng-click="takeSnapshot()">Take snapshot</a>',
        link: function(scope, ele, attrs, cameraCtrl) {
          scope.takeSnapshot = function() {
            cameraCtrl.takeSnapshot()
            .then(function(image) {
              // data image here
            });
          }
        }
      }
    })

</script>
```

in the HTML

```
<body ng-app="app">

<a class="btn btn-info" ng-click="enabled=!enabled">Camera</a>
<!-- ngIf: enabled -->
<div class="camera ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" ng-if="enabled">
<!--camera></camera-->
    <camera>
        <camera-control-snapshot></camera-control-snapshot>
    </camera>
</div><!-- end ngIf: enabled --><!-- end ngIf: enabled --><!-- end ngIf: enabled -->

</body>
```

Comment: You do `<div ng-repeat="cam in webcams">`. Helpful? Neither is your question. Did you actually expect a full answer based on absolutely zero information that you provided about your setup?

Comment: i dont need i full answer, just a tip on how to proceed, but ty anyway, just didnt need to score down...

Comment: People will be thrilled to help you - that's why we're here - if you invest some time in your own question. Read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: angular is javascript ... there is nothing in angular framework that will get the information for you. Research based on that.

Comment: Code added if that helps, tks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong API. Using Google, I found [MDN documentation for Navigator.enumerateDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices). The documentation is for the newer mediaDevices object, but this may be available on the Navigator object for the time being. You'll have to check whether the property exists. Based on the documentation, you should be able to filter the array returned by the function call.

As for Angular, once you have this information, it's as simple as an `ng-repeat`.